# How to get a proper compiler error message when trying to detect if the base class has a virtual destructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

Context: C++11.

Problem, I don't want to inherit from classes that do not define a virtual destructor.

First shot solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define assertHasVirtualDestructor(...) static_assert(std::has_virtual_destructor<__VA_ARGS__>::value, #__VA_ARGS__ );

class Base{};
class A : public Base {
    assertHasVirtualDestructor(Base)
};
```

which

1. doesn't give a nice error message, how is it possible to "concatenate" something to the class name? The ideal error message would be something like "Somebody inherited from class Base which doesn't define a virtual destructor"
2. forces you to express your intents twice (`public Base` and `assertHasVirtualDestructor(Base)`)

The second problem can be easily solved by means of:

```
template <typename Class>
struct SomebodyPubliclyInheritedFrom{
    typedef Class type;
    static_assert(std::has_virtual_destructor<Class>::value, "Somebody publicly inherited from a type which does not define a virtual destructor, error in" );
};

#define publiclyInherits(...) public SomebodyPubliclyInheritedFrom<__VA_ARGS__>::type

class C : publiclyInherits(Base) {};
```

which gives a nice error message apart from it not showing the right context and the name of the derived-from class.

How can I solve this in a portable way?

Comment: What does the preprocessor have to do with this?

Comment: @barman as for question 1 I'm asking how to make the preprocessor generate some nice error message (i.e. string) out of #__VA_ARGS__ and a literal string

moreover, in order to have access to the name of Class in the second  block of code from within SomebodyPubliclyInheritedFrom I think some kind of preprocessing wizardry is needed

Comment: AFAIK, the preprocessor doesn't know anything about classes or inheritance.

Comment: @barman you are right indeed, but the preprocessor is given the name of the base class (namely __VA_ARGS__) and it is the one who should elaborate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can just concatenate two string literally:

```
#define assertHasVirtualDestructor(...) static_assert(std::has_virtual_destructor<__VA_ARGS__>::value, "Somebody inherited from class " #__VA_ARGS__  " which doesn't define a virtual destructor")
```

Error printed by g++:

> x.cpp:7:41: error: static assertion failed: **Somebody inherited from class Base which doesn't define a virtual destructor**
>
> #define assertHasVirtualDestructor(...) static_assert(std::has_virtual_destructor<__VA_ARGS__>::value, "Somebody inherited from class " #__VA_ARGS__  " which doesn't define a virtual destructor")
>
> x.cpp:11:2: note: in expansion of macro 'assertHasVirtualDestructor'
>     assertHasVirtualDestructor(Base);